# Angular 2 - should it be routerLink="theRoute" or [routerLink]="['the route']"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am really confused whether I should be using

```
<a routerLink="/about">About</a>
```

or

```
<a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct.

```
<a routerLink="/about">About</a>
```

and

```
<a [routerLink]="'/about'">About</a>
```

pass a path as string

while

```
<a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
```

passes an array of router commands.

Both are supported.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9d9e9c6ff1eb37d54a6e4af0a88f05a41f75d7a9/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L85

> ```
>   @Input()
>   set routerLink(data: any[]|string) {
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 docs shows usage of :

`<a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>`

It also allows passing objects while routing

Check :-
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#link-parameters-array

Answer (score 0):

You want your url to be passed as an object to the router,
Pass it as

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/myPage']" title="My Page">MyPage</a>,
```

giving it like this

```
<a routerLink="/about">About</a
```

will pass it as a string so will throw error

Comment: There is no error writing the router as in your second example (and it works also)